# Azure Search Bug: Filtering double is same for gt or ge operator on decimals

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Azure Search returns an item with same value as filter value, when filtering on Edm.Double property type, even if we specify "gt" operator.

Example:

```
{ 
    "Price": 822.20 
}
```

`$filter=price gt 822.20` will still return this item (should only return if "ge" operator is specified).

Comment: Hi Niko, I can't reproduce this. Could you share your exact search query and the field definition?

Comment: I have compiled a test suite for my AzureSearchToolkit and this bug appears in CountTests (https://github.com/nkovacic/AzureSearchToolkit/blob/develop/AzureSearchToolkit.IntegrationTest/Tests/CountTests.cs#L61). 
I had to introduce a +1 hack on line 63 to make the integration test to pass.

Comment: Thanks, could you please share the query your code sends to Azure Search?

Comment: `{$count=false&$filter=price%20gt%20825.20&queryType=simple&searchMode=all&$top=200}`


You can find the mock test data in https://github.com/nkovacic/AzureSearchToolkit/blob/develop/AzureSearchToolkit.IntegrationTest/App_Data/listings-mocked.json  

The WhereCount test should return 19 results but it returns 20 and I could confirm that it included the item with the same double value as the filter value.

Comment: @NikoKovačič Can you please let us know which api-version you're using? Also, do your tests create a new Azure Search service, or do they use an existing service that may have existed for some time? Please let us know the region in which the test service is located, and if it's not created every time, please let us know the name. Thanks!

Comment: @BruceJohnston The tests create an index only if it does not exists. Api version is 2017-11-11. The bug exists even if we use azure portal Search explorer. The test service is located in West Europe region and its name is sellaround-dev. We also now noticed that all  [DoubleWhereTests](https://github.com/nkovacic/AzureSearchToolkit/blob/develop/AzureSearchToolkit.IntegrationTest/Tests/Where/DoubleWhereTests.cs) are failing (they all test comparing with double constant).

Comment: @BruceJohnston We have discovered that the bug was in our code, not in Azure Search. There was a rounding problem with translating double values to string. We fixed it in this [commit](https://github.com/nkovacic/AzureSearchToolkit/commit/f3fc377ccb9ded7e1fc7904efe8c007d5aa616e2#diff-e7dda52cb19c3ea10b8eede7a5b47b48L37). Sorrry for wasting your time.

Comment: Thanks @NikoKovačič. If that's the case, how come you could reproduce the issue in the Search Explorer?

Comment: @Yahnoosh I incorrectly assumed that the original value was 822.20 but it was actually.822.201. Because of this mistake I assumed there was a rounding problem in Azure Search (and in extension Search Explorer).